# Problem when the entity value attribute contain special character

Tags: fiware-orion

I have tied to insert in OCB an entity with a password attribute codified:

```
{
        "id": "prueba-tipo-string2",
        "type": "StringParser",
       "dateObserved": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "value": "2020-08-13T08:56:56.00Z"
        },
        "password": {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "U2FsdGVkX10bFP8Rj7xLAQDFwMBphXpK/+leH3mlpQ="
        }
    }
```

- OCB always response to me with the following error:
  "found a forbidden character in the value of an attribute"
- In Postman

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "Invalid characters in attribute value"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion restricts the usage of some characters due to security reasons (script injections attack in some circumstances), see [this piece of documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/forbidden_characters/index.html). In particular, the `=` you have in the `password` attribute `value`.

You can avoid this, for instance, by encoding the password in base 64, or using URL encoding before storing it in Orion.

Another alternative using `TextUnrestricted` in attribute type. This special attribute type does not check if the attribute value contains a forbidden character. However, it could have security implications, use it at your own risk!